# Search from static website

Tags: php, search

I am working on static website, in which i have to implement searchsuch that it search from this site only and give the result with link.

I have no idea to do that.I have to work in PHP

any help will be apriciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

rajanikant just use [jquery search](http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/) to find on page and use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) for your basic reference of php.

Comment: There's also Google's Custom Search API: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/getting_started.html#background-concepts